# Get referenced objected fields from postgresql using node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ejs

i have tow tables in postgres database, account_invoice and res_partner. account_invoice has a relational field of res_partner referenced using id (primary key).

while querying account_invoice the res_partner is appearing as integer instead of name. to solve this i am running another query inside the account_invoice to look up for the res_partner object name field i can view that by logging in the console but cannot render it in the html.

here is my code.

```
<div flex class="main-container">
    <%- include(page) %>
    <ul>
        <% markers.forEach(function (result) { %>
        <li><%= result.invoice_number %></li>
        <% var name = pg.search('res_partner where id = ' + result.partner_id, function(person) { %>
        <% console.log(result.invoice_number + " / " + person[0].name) %>
        <li><%- 'Customer name ' + person[0].name %></li>
        <% }) %>
        <% }) %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is all this goobledygack? This isn't raw nodejs. If you're using a framework/templating engine, include the appropriate tags.

Comment: I am using ejs engine for templates

Comment: Does this actually compile? I don't know ejs but this doesn't look right.